# Getting error when trying to run Test in CommonTest in Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Getting 'Plugin [id: 'com.android.library', version: '7.4.2'] was not found in any of the following sources: ' error when trying to run Test in CommonTest in Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile
When I am trying to run Test in CommonTest in Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile project, I always get this error:

```
Build file '/Users/rageshantonyd/Documents/working_prj/current/livestock-mobile/MobileSharedLib/build.gradle.kts' line: 1
    
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.android.library', version: '7.4.2'] was not found in any of the following sources:
    
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:7.4.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:  
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Why ? Please help me

My gradle files :

https://gist.github.com/RageshAntony/22112e322945617faf8cf01073e8a442

Answer (score 1):

Your error message shows that the plugin is only searched Gradle plugin central.

The Android Gradle plugins is not available in that repository though.

You miss the `google()` repository in our `pluginManagement { repositories { ... } }` section where the plugin is present.

Comment: Google is already in settings.gradle.kts
. I updated the gist. check them please. Thanks

Comment: Hard to guess without seeing the full build. Maybe you use a composite build and have it in the wrong settings script? If `google()` would be in the proper file, it would either work or show it in the error message. Btw. having `mavenCentral()` after `gradlePluginPortal()`  does not make any sense as the Gradle plugin portal redirects to JCenter for things it does not have which forwards to MavenCentral for things it does not have. If at all, then you should have `mavenCentral()` above `gradlePluginPortal()` that would improve performance and protect against the regular JCenter outages.

Comment: I switched like you suggested. Still getting the error

Comment: Again, that was just a side-note. If the repository is not mentioned in the error message, you are not having this in the correct settings script.

Comment: The weird thing is, the app is building and running without any problem(including androidTest's test). Only the tests in CommonTest folder causing this issue when running (it is a KMM project)

Comment: Hard to say for me without seeing the full project. Besides that I'm not too familiar with Android or KMM. :-D

Comment: Did you do a full clearout after all your changes, then start again? Do the following ```./gradlew clean```, then ```./gradlew cleanBuildCache```, then for Android Studio, go to "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart", then just do ```./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies```. After all that, just build project again. Helped me in the past. Cannot see any issue with the gradle files after your changes. There is one other thing to note, the android plugin 7.4.* requires gradle 7.5 minimum to work, but that shouldn't stop it being pulled.